# Disable form altering for admin pages on Bootstrap 3

Tags: theming, ajax, javascript, forms, taxonomy-terms

My default theme is Bootstrap but I use Shiny theme as admin theme. Bootstrap theme alters the forms and fields.

And I use Hierarchical Select module, there is a dropbox for multiselection and the code of submit button for adding terms as below;

```
<input class="add-to-dropbox form-submit" id="edit-field-ana-dizin-und-hierarchical-select-dropbox-add" name="op" value="Add" type="submit">
```

If I use bootstrap despite I use another admin/node edit theme the submit button code showing as below and it does not work like this;

```
<button class="add-to-dropbox btn btn-success form-submit" id="edit-field-ana-dizin-und-hierarchical-select-dropbox-add" name="op" value="Add" type="submit">Add</button>
```

I think This problem is about Ajax query, when ajax script run, the field code altering based on default theme. How can I disable form altering for admin pages?

Thank you.